# correct way to pass ```const char* ptr``` to function, and make a copy of it in the function body

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. I am trying to pass a string to a function *via* `const char* str`. I understand the basic meaning of this passing.

In the function body, when I try `char * ptrStr = str`, I got `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'`. But when I try `auto ptrStr = str`, it works.

I have two questions here: (1) could you please help explain why the former fails while the latter works? (2) how to use smart pointers here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

void func(const char* str){  
    char* ptrStr = str;
}

/*
void func(const char* str){  
    auto ptrStr = str;
}
*/

int main(){
    func("5486321 ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `char*`. Use `std::string` instead and it will work as you expect. There is no point in using smart pointers here, just `std::string` works fine. Neither of the examples make copies of the string. They just copy the pointer pointing to the same string literal.

Comment: You cannot convert a `const` pointer (a pointer to a `const` object/array) to a non-`const` pointer implicitly. And casting the `const` away is usually a really bad idea. Why do you want a non-`const` pointer inside the function?

Comment: @UnholySheep, I want to iterate the string, with *ptrStr++ later. With std::string, there is a better solution

Comment: Later but still inside `func`?  Then just declare `ptrStr` as `const` (or, as you have in your commented-out code, `auto`).

Comment: @PaulSanders, yeah, now I understand in this example ```auto ptrStr = str``` is the same as ```const char* ptrStr = str```.